# How to send email as alias using Django

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-email

### Background:

I have a site I'm building using Django and I've encountered the following conundrum.  I have a backend email that we will call luckyducky@gmail.com.  Now I also have a domain email that forwards directly to luckyduck@gmail.com which is called support@luckyducky.com.

Currently I have my Django Email setting set up as follows:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER="luckyducky@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="password"
```

This works fine, but I want to have the email sent out from 'support@luckyducky.com'.

### Note:

Including the Python community as a whole as maybe the issue can be resolved outside of Django mail wrapper functions.

### Question:

How can I set up this redirection?  Meaning, how can I send out emails under the alias 'support@luckyducky.com' when my true email configured in the Django backend is luckyducky@gmail.com ?

Comment: If you are going to send a lot of email's you can use a service email such as Madnrill App instead of using Django backend.

Comment: Sending emails is a tricky job. Look at Amazon SES, works pretty well and is free for low volume. And has easy to use python API. Once you set the DKIM for your domain, you can start sending signed mails.

Answer (score 8):

`settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` is only used to authenticate with the SMTP server. The third argument of [`django.core.mail.send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) is the `From:` address.

Comment: That said, it's up to the SMTP server whether or not it will allow you send mail claiming to be from the given `From:` address using those credentials. If it doesn't allow it, well, that's probably for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from django documentation
In two lines:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'support@luckyducky.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.